# ruby creating processes and reading output

Tags: ruby, process, nonblocking, process-control

I want to create multiple processes (each with cmd + arguments).

I need the `pid` of the created process so I can kill it if needed.

I also want to be able to read its output (line-by-line) in a non-blocking way (otherwise I have to create threads which I would like to avoid). Feeding its standard input is a bonus.

What's the best way to do this in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`IO.popen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000880) to fork the process (it will return a `IO` object with a `pid` method corresponding to the forked process).  You can `select` on the IO object to avoid blocking.